# C++ code works fine on desktop but not on the laptop

Tags: c++

This simple code for some reason works perfectly fine on my desktop but when I try it on my laptop only the first part (printing the elements of vector) works then the program ends and instead of saying "Process finished with exit code 0" it says
"Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". I don't know what's wrong with my laptop. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int arraysize;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << " " << endl;

    for (it = array.begin(); it < array.end(); it++) {
        if(*it%2==0){
            array.erase(it);
            it--;
        }
    }
    arraysize=array.size();
    cout<<"size:"<<arraysize<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the computer but with the code.

`array.erase(it);` invalidates the iterator `it`, and any subsequent use of it has undefined behaviour.
The worst kind of undefined behaviour is the one that appears to work.

`erase` returns an iterator to the element after the erased one, and you should use that.

```
for (it = array.begin(); it < array.end(); it++) {
    if(*it%2==0){
        it = array.erase(it);
        it--;
    }
}
```

or

```
it = array.begin(); 
while (it < array.end()) {
    if(*it%2==0){
        it = array.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because undefined behaviour can be anything, including exhibiting no apparent problems whatsoever. It can be different on different machines, or on different days of the week, or seemingly completely random.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of iterator invalidation, when you erase an element of the vector the iterator `it` becomes invalidated leading to undefined behaviour, you can read more about this here [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behaviour, you decrement an invalid iterator

```
array.erase(it); // it becomes invalid
it--; // Undefined
```

You can avoid this by removing elements with the "erase-remove" pattern

```
auto is_even = [](int i) { return i%2==0; };
array.erase(std::remove_if(array.begin(), array.end(), is_even), array.end());
```

Or in C++20

```
std::erase_if(array, is_even);
```

Comment: While other answers talk about the quick fix, your answer respectfully doesn't even go there.  You have instead shown the _correct_ way to erase multiple items from a vector!  Nice one. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your laptop. The problem is with the code. When you erase something from the vector, it invalidates the preexisting iterators following the erased elements. You may want to use the return value of `erase`, which references the new reallocated location of the erased element's successor.

Comment: Note that only iterators pointing to or past the erased element are invalidated. Iterators pointing to previous elements should remain intact.